# how to get a lowest id from selected <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created by dynamic TD I have id for each `<tr>`. The `<tr>` are selectable ones. If I select multiple rows, how I get these selectable td's `data-id` in an array or a variable? I want that `data-id`'s and select the lowest id from it.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    tr.setAttribute("data-id", i, 0);
}
```

Like this way I add the `data-id`.

Comment: I'd add a working example, since it's not so much work..

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking. How are you selecting rows? A working example would really help.

Comment: i select the tr using shift key and control key

Comment: And show wht you tried. This isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you need an array of ids that have been added. Here's how you can do it:

```
var ids = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr'))
               .map(function(tr) { return tr.getAttribute('data-id') } );
```

Now, get the the minimum value:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, ids);
```

Comment: its working.  how i get the lowest id(or minimum data id) from this array

Comment: math.min is ok but is there any idea with out using math.min

Comment: You can have a variable initialised as Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY. Now, iterate over the array, if the value in the iteration is less than the variable assign that value to the variable.

Comment: No, I think I have drilled down the problem to a state from where you can take it forward.